# should I remover all [DataType(DataType.Date)] from my models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was having a problem where two fields "BattleStartDate" and "BattleEndDate" where not displaying on my edit form, even though the correct vales had been set on the DB when the record was created. The Create and Edit views both use a common partial View _BattleEditFields.

My old model:

```
    [DisplayName("Battle Start Date")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter date (mm/dd/yyy) when the battle started")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataValidation(ValidationType.RangeValidation, "The battle starting date must be after 1/1/1860 and before 6/1/1865.")]
    public DateTime BattleStartDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Battle End Date")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter date (mm/dd/yyy) when the battle ended")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataValidation(ValidationType.RangeValidation, "The battle ending date must be after 1/1/1860 and before 6/1/1865.")]
    [DataValidation(ValidationType.CompareDates, "The battle ending date must be equal to or greater than the start date.", compareWith: "BattleStartDate")]
    public DateTime BattleEndDate { get; set; }
```

I noticed that at runtime I got the following error message.
error CS0103: The name 'type' does not exist in the current contex

Once I updated the model to removed the [DataType(DataType.Date)] from both fields, every thing worked fine. I have several other date fields that also have [DataType(DataType.Date)] in the model (see below). Should I just go ahead and remove all of them, even though it does not appear to be causing a problem?? (just have to go back an test the change).

-- these are audit type fields and not displayed to the user --

```
  [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime BattleDateAccepted { get; set; }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public string BattleChangedBy { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime BattleDateChange { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally we would advise against this, but it is advised that you try to follow conventions and patterns in your code, so seeing some *Date* properties with this attribute and not others can easily lead to confusion, some developers down the track might add it back to those that are missing, other devs might remove it from all of them as you are suggesting here. So this becomes a *depends* kind of scenario...

Firstly identify why you are using the `DataType(DataType.Date)` attribute in the first place, in MVC the first reason is usually for validation, however this attribute can also be used in DB ORM libraries that manage your database schema like *Entity Framework* to ensure that the *type* of the field in the database should be a *Date ONLY* data type.

- EF has other attributes that can be used for the same purpose, in MVC apps it is common to use a convention to map this attribute to reduce the risk of the two attributes being set with conflicting values.

> If you are using an ORM that needs this attribute to manage the database schema, then each of these attributes that you remove may need a corresponding change set elsewhere in your model to ensure that the DB schema is not affected.

This attribute is heavily referenced in [MVC validation documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and is a the minimal configuration for *Date* input validation. Removing this attribute from the model might still allow invalid values to be accepted through your API, even if the view (*due to your other validation attributes*) correctly generates the validation in the UI. If your API is not exposed to external callers this may not be a concern to you.

> As you have identified that the fields that have this attribute, but are not displayed in the UI do not cause this error you should look into your view code and configuration, to see if you are using a 3rd party control package that is missing a component.
>
> > *'type' does not exist in the current context* is **NOT** a common error associated with this attribute specifically, but could occur with custom control or UI validation code that references mismatched assemblies, usually a .Net FX UI component in a .Net Core project or vice versa.

In your case, if removing the `DataType` attribute resolves your error *AND* has no other adverse effects on your application runtime *OR* deployment, then remove it. If your model is not exposed through an API to external callers or you would not be letting external callers modify the other fields, then for consistency I would recommend removing this attribute from all the DateTime fields.

> Because this is a against the normal MVC expectations for validation, I would include a note about this in your documentation for the model/project so you remember why you have made this decision.

If you have reasons other than validation for keeping the attributes you should investigate further to understand the cause before you apply this to all *Date* fields in your entire model.